# Making Site Live

Tags: web-applications, node.js, port, linode

I'm using Node.JS and MongoDB and have a domain already setup. To show pages I have on my computer (home.html, feature.html, etc.) would I make the Node.js scripts listen to the IP of my server or how exactly would I connect to my server, and display it on my domain?

Comment: What javascript have you written?  The node.js index page has an example of a simple server.  You should probably start there (http://nodejs.org/).

Comment: I wrote script like that. The node.js script works (tested it with .listen(3000)) but I'm trying to make it so it can appear to everyone.

Comment: Does the server have a public IP, and do you know what it is?

Answer (score 1):

When you call the listen function, you can specify the hostname that you want the server to listen on. This is only beneficial in instances where you want to run multiple domains with different code. [According to the documentation:](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/http.html#server.listen)

> server.listen(port, [hostname], [callback])
>
> Begin accepting connections on the specified port and hostname. If the hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections directed to any IPv4 address (INADDR_ANY).

An example usage is as follows:

```
server.listen(80, 'mydomain.com');
```

To connect your domain to your computer, you need to setup the DNS records to point to the computer's external static IP address, or use a [dynamic DNS service](http://dyndns.org/) if you don't have a static IP address. If your computer is not directly connected to the internet, you will need to setup port forwarding on your router.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to listen to a port only, and access it with a browser and this URL

> domainname.com:portnumber

Or just use the direct IP for testing purposes:

> IP-address:portnumber

Comment: Both of them throw an error in node.js. For "domain.com:portnumber" I get "Unexpected : token" and for "123.123.123.123:port" I get "Unexpected Number." For both I used "node server.js" in ssh